# How server alone can push data to client browser using python and websockets

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to push some messages to client (browser) without any request.
For that I use WebSockets and python to do. I know WebSockets provide a full-duplex communication, but I just need server to client push. I could only find bi-directional communication examples for WebSockets over internet, for a request a response model. When I tried to send in an infinite loop from server after handshake process, the browser hung up.

the code I used is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986514/established-a-handshake-websocket-connection-how-could-a-server-push-data-infin)

Is there any solution to do that or whether it is better to go for SSE..

Comment: For a protocol on top of WebSocket which does what you want, take a look at http://wamp.ws. This connects both the browser and your backend to a WAMP router, and the backend can then push to the client. Plenty of client implementations there as well, so that you should find something that fits your tech stack on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Once the client initiates the web socket connection the server then is eligible to send anything to client side

Comment: ah yes.. but I cannot find any working example that a server is sending messages to client without any request..

Comment: Web Socket API implemented in browsers are client side only - not Peer-to-Peer and not Server Side.  He who initiates the request is always considered the client - the other side always the server ... although I now wonder if you Browserify a node.js ws module so it runs in the Browser if this can be circumvented ...

Comment: Scott, thanks for your comments. lemme try to Browserify node.js